# How to use a variable as the width modifier without outputting zeroes

Tags: c

I have this typed:

```
 printf("Original Value: %.*d\n", mover, value);
 printf("After change #%d: %.*d\n", ct, mover, value);
```

this is what is output from my code:

```
Original Value:  1233456
After change #1: 0012456
```

The value calculated from the rest of my code for after change #1 is 12456, so I need the zeroes to not be in front of the after change value but I still need the 6 of the original to line up with the 6 of the after change 1.  Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? (**mover is equal to the number of digits in Original Value**)

Answer (score 1):

Use `%*d` to get output without leading zeros.